# How can JQuery AJAX requests trigger Angular ng-click directives

Tags: jquery, ajax, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have been using a mixture of JQuery and Angular in a mobile application. I am occasionally running into a really weird bug.

The elements with the Angular directives are in a partial that is included using a `ng-include` directive:

```
<ng-include src="'../partials/_childnav.html'" autoscroll=""></ng-include>
```

And the partial has a couple of navigation components:

```
<div class="nav-home" ng-click="navHome()"></div>
<div class="nav-back" ng-click="navBack()"></div>
```

These divs are not referenced anywhere in the code (the classes are just for styling) and the functions are only called from these directives: so for those functions to be called, a physical tap (click) should be the only way.

On my search page, I use a simple `$.ajax()` call to get some results for a pre-set query.  This is done on the page's visibility change event and its results are used to make many changes to the `$scope`. Usually everything works as intended, but not always.

The bug I am running into is that randomly (but only if the AJAX request completes very quickly), the `ng-click` directives on those navigation components seem to get called.

To add even more weirdness to it, when this bug occurs, it seems to be looking for buttons to press. As it is, `navHome()` usually ends up being called, but if I remove that directive:

```
<div class="nav-home"></div>
<div class="nav-back" ng-click="navBack()"></div>
```

then navBack() gets called. If i remove both, the bug doesn't happen (obviously this is not a solution).

Edit: Using click handlers instead of `ng-click` directives produces the same result, so something is triggering the click events on the divs.

I would love to get an explanation of how this can actually happen, the behavior is simply absurd to me.

Comment: What's in the callback of your ajax call (both success and error)?

Comment: Have you tried to set a breakpoint in the code and look at the call stack to figure out what's calling these methods?

Comment: Mixing jQuery and Angular can produce some very weird results - Angular requires `$digest` cycles to run to bind the view back to the model - jQuery's `$.ajax` doesnt trigger a cycle, so it must be manually triggered. If you're appending HTML in the `$.ajax`, that HTML must be compiled against the `$scope` else Angular methods won't be accessible.

Comment: use the $http service to make your ajax call.  no reason not too.  we will need some sort of fiddle/plunker most likely to help.

Comment: @Simon, other than the fluff, the success handler just cleans up the results in the response and attaches them to a scope variable. I then use `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();` to get Angular to do its magic (the variable is used in a `ng-repeat` in the html). Failure handler is supposed to show an error message (in a div) but it is just writing log messages at the moment. All of this actually works just fine normally, just once in a while when it completes too quickly, click events are fired on the divs?!

Comment: @Edminsson, yes and the code is covered with logging as well (been stuck here for a while). However, when the click events happen, it is during jquery's ajax function, before success/error handlers are fired so I will replace my minified one with the debug version so i can see where in jquery code this happens. I still think it is an Angular problem but just knowing where exactly it starts would help.

Comment: @tymeJV, yes, while searching i ran into many examples of problems caused when they are used together but haven't run into this anywhere. As I was saying to Simon, I am manually triggering the cycle after populating the template variable, the AJAX request is just to get data, no html. And once again, it works perfectly fine most of the time. Those `$digest` cycles are what I am most suspicious of at the moment; the bug very much seems like a timing issue. i need to look into how to debug those cycles :/ my understanding is that `if (!$scope.$$phase) $scope.$apply();` should be timing safe.

Comment: and @glandrum101, I will most likely end up going that way, Angular came in late in the project when I already had a lot of functionality completed using jquery and I am on a tight deadline (and a beginner in Angular) so quiet a bit of jquery is still around. Regardless, you know what it is like with developers and unexplained phenomenon, I really need to figure out how all this is happening or it will drive me nuts :/

Comment: Seems I was on the wrong track, sorry for taking your time. There is a problem but it seems the problem is with the webview itself. I have noticed the buttons weren't random but were in fact the last navigation button pressed on the search page. And it was always triggered by the XMLHttpRequest.send. I have rebuilt the app using an older client (with an older webview) and the bug disappears. I will create a separate question about that but what do you think i should do with this one? Do people think it would be helpful to others if i left it or should i delete it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a problem with the development environment (AppGyver Steroids). I could work around it by using certain combinations of their build and JS library versions but the bug is in closed source code and it's developers didn't care to investigate so this question won't get resolved.